# mdframed or shaded inside mdframed?

Tags: memoir, mdframed

I have an `mdframed` environment and i want another frame, just with background color, inside it but i don't wish to have the above title inherited.

That's why i used the shaded environment. My problem is that i can't align the inner `shaded` box with the inner lines of the outer.

Is there a way that i can fit both boxes perfectly, with no whitespace and no overlaps of one on top of the other?

```
\documentclass[9pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathspec,xltxtra}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!10}

\newcounter{solved}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thesolved}{\thechapter.\arabic{solved}}
\newenvironment{solved}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{solved}
\begin{mdframed}[%
    frametitle={\textbf{\Large{SOLVED EXAMPLE} \thesolved}\ \\ #1},
    frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlerulewidth=1pt,
    frametitlerulecolor=black,
    innertopmargin=-0.7em,%
    innerleftmargin=0.4em,%,
    hidealllines=true,leftline=true,
    %frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!70,
    linewidth=10pt,
    linecolor=gray!80,
    %fontcolor=white,%
    %backgroundcolor=gray!10
]%
}{%
\end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{solved}[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet]
\begin{shaded}
Solve this one

\begin{enumerate}
 \item
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  
 \item
 Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
\item
Velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
\end{enumerate}
\end{shaded}

\b{\Large{SOLUTION}}

\noindent
Velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
\end{solved}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use another `mdframed` for the inner shaded area. For this define a style like

```
\mdfdefinestyle{style2}{frametitle={},innertopmargin=5pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
             linewidth=2pt,hidealllines=true,topline=true,backgroundcolor=gray!20}
```

and apply it to the inner `mdframed` environment.

```
\documentclass[9pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{mathspec,xltxtra}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!10}

\newcounter{solved}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thesolved}{\thechapter.\arabic{solved}}
\newenvironment{solved}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{solved}
\begin{mdframed}[%
    frametitle={\hspace{0.5em}\textbf{\Large SOLVED EXAMPLE \thesolved}\ \\ \hspace*{0.5em}#1},
    frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlerulewidth=1pt,
    frametitlerulecolor=black,
    innertopmargin=0em,%
    innerleftmargin=0em,%,
    innerrightmargin=0em,
    hidealllines=true,leftline=true,
    %frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!70,
    linewidth=10pt,
    linecolor=gray!80,
    %fontcolor=white,%
    %backgroundcolor=gray!10
]%
}{%
\end{mdframed}
}

\mdfdefinestyle{style1}{frametitle={},innertopmargin=0pt,
             linewidth=0.5em,linecolor=white,hidealllines=true,rightline=true,leftline=true,
             }
\mdfdefinestyle{style2}{frametitle={},innertopmargin=5pt,innerrightmargin=0.5em,%
             linewidth=2pt,linecolor=gray!20,hidealllines=true,topline=true,leftline=true,
             linewidth=0.4em,backgroundcolor=gray!20}

\begin{document}
\begin{solved}[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet]
\begin{mdframed}[style=style2]
Solve this one

\begin{enumerate}
 \item
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
 \item
 Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
\item
Velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
\end{enumerate}
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[style=style1]
{\bfseries\Large{SOLUTION}}

\noindent
Velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
\end{mdframed}
\end{solved}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, i was also wondering if i could eliminate the white space around the inner box

Comment: @SofiaMouseti Please see the edit. If you need a `tcolorbox` variant, let me know.

Comment: thank u, but the problem is that  everytime the outer 'solved'  example is very big and has to break in multiple pages, it shows the first frame and then it breaks the second inner frame (the one with the solution) in a new page